# What's the simplest way to print a Java array?

Tags: java, arrays, printing, tostring

In Java, arrays don't override `toString()`, so if you try to print one directly, you get the `className` + '@' + the hex of the [`hashCode`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_hashCode()) of the array, as defined by `Object.toString()`:

```java
int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
System.out.println(intArray); // Prints something like '[I@3343c8b3'
```

But usually, we'd actually want something more like `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]`. What's the simplest way of doing that? Here are some example inputs and outputs:

```java
// Array of primitives:
int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
// Output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

// Array of object references:
String[] strArray = new String[] {"John", "Mary", "Bob"};
// Output: [John, Mary, Bob]
```

Comment: What do you want the representation to be for objects other than strings? The result of calling toString? In quotes or not?

Comment: Yes objects would be represented by their toString() method and without quotes (just edited the example output).

Comment: In practice, closely related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29140402/how-do-i-print-my-java-object-without-getting-sometype2f92e0f4

Comment: That weird output is not necessarily the memory location. It's the `hashCode()` in hexadecimal. See [`Object#toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--).

Comment: To print single dimensional or multi-dimensional array in java8 check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array/30931066#30931066

Comment: Related: [*Convert array of strings into a string in Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5283444/3357935) & [*How do I print my Java object without getting “SomeType@2f92e0f4”?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29140402/3357935)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191507/objects-deeptostringobject-o-method

Answer (score 3212, accepted):

Since Java 5 you can use [`Arrays.toString(arr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#toString(int%5B%5D)) or [`Arrays.deepToString(arr)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object%5B%5D)) for arrays within arrays. Note that the `Object[]` version calls `.toString()` on each object in the array. The output is even decorated in the exact way you're asking.

Examples:

- #### Simple Array:

  ```
  String[] array = new String[] {"John", "Mary", "Bob"};
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  [John, Mary, Bob]
  ```
- #### Nested Array:

  ```
  String[][] deepArray = new String[][] {{"John", "Mary"}, {"Alice", "Bob"}};
  // Gives undesired output:
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(deepArray));
  // Gives the desired output:
  System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(deepArray));
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  [[Ljava.lang.String;@106d69c, [Ljava.lang.String;@52e922]
  [[John, Mary], [Alice, Bob]]
  ```
- #### `double` Array:

  ```
  double[] doubleArray = { 7.0, 9.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0 };
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(doubleArray));
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  [7.0, 9.0, 5.0, 1.0, 3.0 ]
  ```
- #### `int` Array:

  ```
  int[] intArray = { 7, 9, 5, 1, 3 };
  System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
  ```

  Output:

  ```
  [7, 9, 5, 1, 3 ]
  ```

Comment: What if we have an array of strings, and want simple output; like: `String[] array = {"John", "Mahta", "Sara"}`, and we want this output without bracket and commas: `John Mahta Sara`?

Comment: @Hengameh: There are several other ways to do this, but my favorite is this one: http://www.javahotchocolate.com/notes/java.html#arrays-tostring .

Comment: FYI, `Arrays.deepToString()` accepts only an `Object []` (or an array of classes that extend `Object`, such as `Integer`, so it won't work on a primitive array of type `int []`.  But `Arrays.toString(<int array>)` works fine for primitive arrays.

Comment: @Hengameh There's a method dedicated to that. `System.out.println(String.join(" ", new String[]{"John", "Mahta", "Sara"}))` will print `John Mahta Sara`.

Comment: @dorukayhan Actually you can omit explicitly instantiating the array here: `String.join(" ", "John", "Mahta", "Sara")`for the `.join(...)` method takes the array as a _vararg_ parameter.

Comment: Don't forget "import java.util.Arrays;"

Comment: If you don't import, you can write `java.util.Arrays.toString(array)`

Comment: Also, don't forget to override `Object#toString()` if the array contains an object type other than `String` or a primitive wrapper class.

Answer (score 431):

Always check the standard libraries first.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
```

Then try:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
```

or if your array contains other arrays as elements:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
```

Comment: @Hengameh Nowadays with Java 8: `String.join(" ", Arrays.asList(array))`. [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.Iterable-)

Answer (score 115):

This is nice to know, however, as for "always check the standard libraries first" I'd never have stumbled upon the trick of `Arrays.toString( myarray )`

--since I was concentrating on the type of myarray to see how to do this. I didn't want to have to iterate through the thing: I wanted an easy call to make it come out similar to what I see in the Eclipse debugger and myarray.toString() just wasn't doing it.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
.
.
.
System.out.println( Arrays.toString( myarray ) );
```

Answer (score 112):

In JDK1.8 you can use aggregate operations and a lambda expression:

```
String[] strArray = new String[] {"John", "Mary", "Bob"};

// #1
Arrays.asList(strArray).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));

// #2
Stream.of(strArray).forEach(System.out::println);

// #3
Arrays.stream(strArray).forEach(System.out::println);

/* output:
John
Mary
Bob
*/
```

Answer (score 56):

### Arrays.toString

As a direct answer, [the solution provided by several, including @Esko](https://stackoverflow.com/a/409795/365237), using the [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) and [`Arrays.deepToString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString%28java.lang.Object%5B%5D%29) methods, is simply the best.

### Java 8 - Stream.collect(joining()), Stream.forEach

Below I try to list some of the other methods suggested, attempting to improve a little, with the most notable addition being the use of the [`Stream.collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) operator, using a [`joining`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining-java.lang.CharSequence-) `Collector`, to mimic what the `String.join` is doing.

```
int[] ints = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
System.out.println(IntStream.of(ints).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
System.out.println(IntStream.of(ints).boxed().map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));

String[] strs = new String[] {"John", "Mary", "Bob"};
System.out.println(Stream.of(strs).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
System.out.println(String.join(", ", strs));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strs));

DayOfWeek [] days = { FRIDAY, MONDAY, TUESDAY };
System.out.println(Stream.of(days).map(Object::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(days));

// These options are not the same as each item is printed on a new line:
IntStream.of(ints).forEach(System.out::println);
Stream.of(strs).forEach(System.out::println);
Stream.of(days).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: if you use 
IntStream.of(ints).forEach(System.out::print); i don't think it will print in new line..

Answer (score 51):

Starting with Java 8, one could also take advantage of the `join()` method provided by the [String class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) to print out array elements, without the brackets, and separated by a delimiter of choice (which is the space character for the example shown below):

```
String[] greeting = {"Hey", "there", "amigo!"};
String delimiter = " ";
String.join(delimiter, greeting)
```

The output will be "Hey there amigo!".

Answer (score 46):

### Prior to Java 8

We could have used `Arrays.toString(array)` to print one dimensional array and `Arrays.deepToString(array)` for multi-dimensional arrays.

### Java 8

Now we have got the option of `Stream` and `lambda` to print the array.

**Printing One dimensional Array:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    String[] strArray = new String[] {"John", "Mary", "Bob"};

    //Prior to Java 8
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));

    // In Java 8 we have lambda expressions
    Arrays.stream(intArray).forEach(System.out::println);
    Arrays.stream(strArray).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

The output is:

> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>   [John, Mary, Bob]
>   1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>   5
>   John
>   Mary
>   Bob

**Printing Multi-dimensional Array**
Just in case we want to print multi-dimensional array we can use `Arrays.deepToString(array)` as:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] int2DArray = new int[][] { {11, 12}, { 21, 22}, {31, 32, 33} };
    String[][] str2DArray = new String[][]{ {"John", "Bravo"} , {"Mary", "Lee"}, {"Bob", "Johnson"} };

    //Prior to Java 8
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(int2DArray));
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(str2DArray));

    // In Java 8 we have lambda expressions
    Arrays.stream(int2DArray).flatMapToInt(x -> Arrays.stream(x)).forEach(System.out::println);
    Arrays.stream(str2DArray).flatMap(x -> Arrays.stream(x)).forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Now the point to observe is that the method `Arrays.stream(T[])`, which in case of `int[]` returns us `Stream<int[]>` and then method `flatMapToInt()` maps each element of stream with the contents of a mapped stream produced by applying the provided mapping function to each element.

The output is:

> [[11, 12], [21, 22], [31, 32, 33]]
>   [[John, Bravo], [Mary, Lee], [Bob, Johnson]]
>   11
>   12
>   21
>   22
>   31
>   32
>   33
>   John
>   Bravo
>   Mary
>   Lee
>   Bob
>   Johnson

Answer (score 43):

If you're using Java 1.4, you can instead do:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
```

(This works in 1.5+ too, of course.)

Comment: Unfortunately this only works with arrays of objects, not arrays of primitives.

Answer (score 30):

`Arrays.deepToString(arr)` only prints on one line.

```
int[][] table = new int[2][2];
```

To actually get a table to print as a two dimensional table, I had to do this:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(table).replaceAll("],", "]," + System.getProperty("line.separator")));
```

It seems like the `Arrays.deepToString(arr)` method should take a separator string, but unfortunately it doesn't.

Comment: Maybe use System.getProperty("line.separator"); instead of \r\n so it is right for non-Windows as well.

Answer (score 20):

```
for(int n: someArray) {
    System.out.println(n+" ");
}
```

Comment: This way you end up with an empty space ;)

Comment: @ matthiad .. this line will avoid ending up with empty space  System.out.println(n+ (someArray.length == n) ? "" : " ");

Comment: @MuhammadSuleman That doesn't work, because this is a for-each loop. `n` is the actual value from the array, not the index. For a regular for loop, it would also be `(someArray.length - 1) == i`, because it breaks when `i` is equal to the array length.

Answer (score 18):

**Different Ways to Print Arrays in Java:**

1. Simple Way

   ```
   List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
   list.add("One");
   list.add("Two");
   list.add("Three");
   list.add("Four");
   // Print the list in console
   System.out.println(list);
   ```

> Output:
>       [One, Two, Three, Four]

2. Using **`toString()`**

   ```
   String[] array = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four" };
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
   ```

> Output: [One, Two, Three, Four]

3. Printing Array of Arrays

   ```
   String[] arr1 = new String[] { "Fifth", "Sixth" };
   String[] arr2 = new String[] { "Seventh", "Eight" };
   String[][] arrayOfArray = new String[][] { arr1, arr2 };
   System.out.println(arrayOfArray);
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayOfArray));
   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(arrayOfArray));
   ```

> Output: [[Ljava.lang.String;@1ad086a [[Ljava.lang.String;@10385c1,
>   [Ljava.lang.String;@42719c] [[Fifth, Sixth], [Seventh, Eighth]]

Resource: [Access An Array](http://howtodoinjava.com/core-java/collections/how-to-print-the-content-of-array-in-java/)

Answer (score 12):

Using regular **for** loop is the simplest way of printing array in my opinion.
Here you have a sample code based on your intArray

```
for (int i = 0; i < intArray.length; i++) {
   System.out.print(intArray[i] + ", ");
}
```

It gives output as yours
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5

Comment: It prints "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, " as output, it prints comma after the last element too.

Comment: You could replace the code within the loop with
`System.out.print(intArray[i]);
if(i != intArray.length - 1) System.out.print(", ");`

Comment: You could also use `System.out.print(i + (i < intArray.length - 1 ? ", " : ""));` to combine those two lines.

Answer (score 12):

It should always work whichever JDK version you use:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array));
```

It will work if the `Array` contains Objects. If the `Array` contains primitive types, you can use wrapper classes instead storing the primitive directly as..

Example:

```
int[] a = new int[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

Replace it with:

```
Integer[] a = new Integer[]{1,2,3,4,5};
```

**Update :**

Yes ! this is to be mention that converting an array to an object array OR to use the Object's array is costly and may slow the execution. it happens by the nature of java called autoboxing.

So only for printing purpose, It should not be used. we can make a function which takes an array as parameter and prints the desired format as

```
public void printArray(int [] a){
        //write printing code
}
```

Comment: Converting an Array to a List simply for printing purposes does not seem like a very resourceful decision; and given that the same class has a `toString(..)`, it defeats me why someone would ever do this.

Answer (score 9):

I came across this post in [Vanilla #Java](http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2016/03/printing-arrays-by-hacking-jvm.html) recently. It's not very convenient writing `Arrays.toString(arr);`, then importing `java.util.Arrays;` all the time.

**Please note, this is not a permanent fix by any means. Just a hack that can make debugging simpler.**

Printing an array directly gives the internal representation and the hashCode. Now, all classes have `Object` as the parent-type. So, why not hack the `Object.toString()`? Without modification, the Object class looks like this:

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

What if this is changed to:

```
public String toString() {
    if (this instanceof boolean[])
        return Arrays.toString((boolean[]) this);
    if (this instanceof byte[])
        return Arrays.toString((byte[]) this);
    if (this instanceof short[])
        return Arrays.toString((short[]) this);
    if (this instanceof char[])
        return Arrays.toString((char[]) this);
    if (this instanceof int[])
        return Arrays.toString((int[]) this);
    if (this instanceof long[])
        return Arrays.toString((long[]) this);
    if (this instanceof float[])
        return Arrays.toString((float[]) this);
    if (this instanceof double[])
        return Arrays.toString((double[]) this);
    if (this instanceof Object[])
        return Arrays.deepToString((Object[]) this);
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

This modded class may simply be added to the class path by adding the following to the command line: `-Xbootclasspath/p:target/classes`.

Now, with the availability of `deepToString(..)` since Java 5, the `toString(..)` can easily be changed to `deepToString(..)` to add support for arrays that contain other arrays.

I found this to be a quite useful hack and it would be great if Java could simply add this. I understand potential issues with having very large arrays since the string representations could be problematic. Maybe pass something like a `System.out`or a `PrintWriter` for such eventualities.

Answer (score 9):

In java 8 it is easy. there are two keywords

1. stream: `Arrays.stream(intArray).forEach`
2. method reference: `::println`

   ```
   int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
   Arrays.stream(intArray).forEach(System.out::println);
   ```

If you want to print all elements in the array in the same line, then just use `print` instead of `println` i.e.

```
int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
Arrays.stream(intArray).forEach(System.out::print);
```

Another way without method reference just use:

```
int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));
```

Answer (score 7):

You could loop through the array,  printing out each item, as you loop. For example:

```
String[] items = {"item 1", "item 2", "item 3"};

for(int i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {

    System.out.println(items[i]);

}
```

Output:

```
item 1
item 2
item 3
```

Answer (score 7):

- It is very simple way to print array without using any loop in JAVA.

  -> For, Single or simple array:

  ```
   int[] array = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
   System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));
  ```

  The Output :

  ```
        [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
  ```

  -> So, this 2D array can't be printed with Arrays.toString()

  ```
   int[][] array = new int[][]{{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7}, {8, 9, 10, 11, 12,13,14}};
   System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(array));
  ```

  The Output:

  ```
     [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]]
  ```

Answer (score 6):

**There Are Following way to print Array**

```
 // 1) toString()  
    int[] arrayInt = new int[] {10, 20, 30, 40, 50};  
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arrayInt));

// 2 for loop()
    for (int number : arrayInt) {
        System.out.println(number);
    }

// 3 for each()
    for(int x: arrayInt){
         System.out.println(x);
     }
```

Answer (score 5):

There's one additional way if your array is of type char[]:

```
char A[] = {'a', 'b', 'c'}; 

System.out.println(A); // no other arguments
```

prints

```
abc
```

Answer (score 4):

A simplified shortcut I've tried is this:

```
    int x[] = {1,2,3};
    String printableText = Arrays.toString(x).replaceAll("[\\[\\]]", "").replaceAll(", ", "\n");
    System.out.println(printableText);
```

It will print

```
1
2
3
```

No loops required in this approach and it is best for small arrays only

Answer (score 4):

Using org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.join(*) methods can be an option
For example:

```
String[] strArray = new String[] { "John", "Mary", "Bob" };
String arrayAsCSV = StringUtils.join(strArray, " , ");
System.out.printf("[%s]", arrayAsCSV);
//output: [John , Mary , Bob]
```

I used the following dependency

```
<groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
<version>3.3.2</version>
```

Comment: Adding a dependency because of something trivial that be done in two lines of code is a screaming antipattern.

Comment: commons-lang3 is a very poplar dependency, and note that this answer was were most people didn't used java 8

Comment: Still the best solution as also referred in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38425623/java-join-array-of-primitives-with-separator
commons-lang is of course really popular and should be used instead of implement yourself. Such utility methods have to be tested and should also be accessible for other projects. As long as primitive arrays can not simple handled, a library like common-lang with overloaded methods is for me the best and efficient way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 4):

For-each loop can also be used to print elements of array:

```
int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int i:array)
    System.out.println(i);
```

Comment: @firephil System.out.println(a[i]); is used with ordinary for loop, where index "i" is created and value at every index is printed. I have used "for each" loop. Give it a try, hope you will get my point.

Answer (score 3):

To add to all the answers, printing the object as a JSON string is also an option.

Using Jackson:

```
ObjectWriter ow = new ObjectMapper().writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
System.out.println(ow.writeValueAsString(anyArray));
```

Using Gson:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
System.out.println(gson.toJson(anyArray));
```

Comment: This is what I do.  With this, you can print arbitrarily complex structures as long as they're encodable to JSON. I always make sure to use "pretty".  Does your second example do that?  I'd think you'd need to tickle a "pretty" option to get that.

Answer (score 3):

```
// array of primitives:
int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(intArray));

output: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

---

```
// array of object references:
String[] strArray = new String[] {"John", "Mary", "Bob"};

System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strArray));

output: [John, Mary, Bob]
```

Answer (score 3):

Here a possible printing function:

```
  public static void printArray (int [] array){
        System.out.print("{ ");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
            System.out.print("[" + array[i] + "] ");
        }
        System.out.print("}");
    }
```

For example, if main is like this

```
public static void main (String [] args){
    int [] array = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    printArray(array);
}
```

the output will be { [1] [2] [3] [4] }

Answer (score 2):

```
public class printer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String a[] = new String[4];
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("enter the data");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            a[i] = sc.nextLine();
        }
        System.out.println("the entered data is");
        for (String i : a) {
            System.out.println(i);
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is marked as a duplicate for [printing a byte[]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50977959/cannot-see-the-contents-of-the-array-printed-in-console). Note: for a byte array there are additional methods which may be appropriate.

You can print it as a String if it contains ISO-8859-1 chars.

```
String s = new String(bytes, StandardChars.ISO_8559);
System.out.println(s);
// to reverse
byte[] bytes2 = s.getBytes(StandardChars.ISO_8559);
```

or if it contains a UTF-8 string

```
String s = new String(bytes, StandardChars.UTF_8);
System.out.println(s);
// to reverse
byte[] bytes2 = s.getBytes(StandardChars.UTF_8);
```

or if you want print it as hexadecimal.

```
String s = DatatypeConverter.printHexBinary(bytes);
System.out.println(s);
// to reverse
byte[] bytes2 = DatatypeConverter.parseHexBinary(s);
```

or if you want print it as base64.

```
String s = DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(bytes);
System.out.println(s);
// to reverse
byte[] bytes2 = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(s);
```

or if you want to print an array of signed byte values

```
String s = Arrays.toString(bytes);
System.out.println(s);
// to reverse
String[] split = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).split(", ");
byte[] bytes2 = new byte[split.length];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes2.length; i++)
    bytes2[i] = Byte.parseByte(split[i]);
```

or if you want to print an array of unsigned byte values

```
String s = Arrays.toString(
               IntStream.range(0, bytes.length).map(i -> bytes[i] & 0xFF).toArray());
System.out.println(s);
// to reverse
String[] split = s.substring(1, s.length() - 1).split(", ");
byte[] bytes2 = new byte[split.length];
for (int i = 0; i < bytes2.length; i++)
    bytes2[i] = (byte) Integer.parseInt(split[i]); // might need a range check.
```

Answer (score 2):

if you are running jdk 8.

```
public static void print(int[] array) {
    StringJoiner joiner = new StringJoiner(",", "[", "]");
    Arrays.stream(array).forEach(element -> joiner.add(element + ""));
    System.out.println(joiner.toString());
}


int[] array = new int[]{7, 3, 5, 1, 3};
print(array);
```

output:

```
[7,3,5,1,3]
```

Comment: This is better than the accepted answer in that it gives more control over the delimiter, prefix and suffix. However, I would remove superfluous `toString()` in the final `System.out.println()` and used it in `joiner.add(element.toString())` instead of adding the empty string. This solution works for arrays of non-primitive types as well, uniformly.

Comment: My bad, `element.toString()` inside `joiner.add()` is for non-primitive types only. You still need to use `Integer.toString(element)` - like constructs for primitive types. Personally, I used foreach loop `for (int element : array) joiner.add(Integer.toString(element));` instead of streams, but that's the matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Java 11

```
import java.util.Arrays;
public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        String[] array = { "John", "Mahta", "Sara" };
       System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array).replace(",", "").replace("[", "").replace("]", ""));
     }
}
```

Output :

```
John Mahta Sara
```

Answer (score 1):

In java 8 :

```
Arrays.stream(myArray).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Those who created a vote to remove my answer .. can you expose your point of view so everyone can learn ?  The question asked for the simplest way in java, so it's a one liner, java current version is >14 and my solution is for at least java 8 ( so it is applicable ).

Answer (score 1):

If using [Commons.Lang library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/), we could do:

`ArrayUtils.toString(array)`

```
int[] intArray = new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
String[] strArray = new String[] {"John", "Mary", "Bob"};
ArrayUtils.toString(intArray);
ArrayUtils.toString(strArray);
```

Output:

```
{1,2,3,4,5}
{John,Mary,Bob}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JDK1.8 you can use aggregate operations and a lambda expression:

```
String[] strArray = new String[] {"John", "Mary", "Bob"};

// #1
Arrays.asList(strArray).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));

// #2
Stream.of(strArray).forEach(System.out::println);

 // #3
 Arrays.stream(strArray).forEach(System.out::println);

/* output:
John
Mary
Bob
*/
```

Also, starting with Java 8, one could also take advantage of the join() method provided by the String class to print out array elements, without the brackets, and separated by a delimiter of choice (which is the space character for the example shown below)

```
string[] greeting = {"Hey", "there", "amigo!"};
String delimiter = " ";
String.join(delimiter, greeting)
```

`
The output will be "Hey there amigo!"

Answer (score 0):

By using the java.util.Arrays:

```
String mRole = "M_XXX_ABC";        
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(mRole.split("_")).toString());
```

output: [M, XXX, ABC]

Answer (score 0):

Use the Arrays class. It has multiple utility methods and its `toString()` is overriden to display array elements in a human readable way.
`Arrays.toString(arr)`

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways to print an array elements.First of all,  I'll explain that, what is an array?..Array is a simple data structure for storing data..When you define an array , Allocate set of ancillary memory blocks in RAM.Those memory blocks are taken  one unit ..

Ok, I'll create an array like this,

```
class demo{
      public static void main(String a[]){

           int[] number={1,2,3,4,5};

           System.out.print(number);
      }
}
```

Now look at the output,

[image]

You can see an unknown string printed..As I mentioned before, the memory address whose array(number array) declared is printed.If you want to display elements in the array, you can use "for loop " , like this..

```
class demo{
      public static void main(String a[]){

           int[] number={1,2,3,4,5};

           int i;

           for(i=0;i<number.length;i++){
                 System.out.print(number[i]+"  ");
           }
      }
}
```

Now look at the output,

[image]

Ok,Successfully printed elements of one dimension  array..Now I am going to consider two dimension array..I'll declare two dimension array as "number2" and print the elements using "Arrays.deepToString()" keyword.Before using that You will have to import 'java.util.Arrays' library.

```
 import java.util.Arrays;

 class demo{
      public static void main(String a[]){

           int[][] number2={{1,2},{3,4},{5,6}};`

           System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(number2));
      }
}
```

consider the output,

[image]

At the same time , Using two for loops ,2D elements can be printed..Thank you !

Comment: int array[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
for (int i:array)
    System.out.println(i);

Comment: try this i think this is shortest way to print array

Comment: "the memory address whose array(number array) declared is printed" That's not true at all, its system hash code of object, and this can be based on many things, including memory address, but this could change later and hash code would not change. And currently its mostly a random number. https://gotofinal.dev/java/2017/10/08/java-default-hashcode.html

Answer (score -1):

toString is a way to convert an array to string.

Also, you can use:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++){
System.out.println(myArray[i] + " ");
}
```

This for loop will enable you to print each value of your array in order.

Answer (score -2):

For Android developers ending up here, this is for Kotlin:

```kotlin
println(myArray.joinToString())
```

OR

```kotlin
println(myArray.joinToString(separator = "|"))
```